# how to delete all folders except some folders

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

Hello I need to delete all folders in a folder but i got stuck cause i need to not delete two folders. I wanted to do something like this:

```
string[] dir = Directory.GetDirectories(getDir());

foreach(string r in (dir.Where(x => x.Contains("AutomaticRecepes") == false))&& 
dir.Where(y => y.Contains("SpecialRecepes") == false))
{
    Directory.Delete(r, true);
}
```

so as you can see i want (with a few lines of code) to delete every folder except for the folders that have the name AutomaticRecepes and SpecialRecepes.

Of course the code i wrote gives error:

> operator && can not be applied to operand of type 'system.collections.generic.ienumerable' and 'system.collections.generic.ienumerable'

How can i do it?

thank you

Comment: You have to replace `...  x.Contains("AutomaticRecepes") == false))` by removing the last parentheses so `...  x.Contains("AutomaticRecepes") == false)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do is

```
List<string> FileNames = dir.Where(x => !x.Contains("AutomaticRecepes") && !x.Contains("SpecialRecepes")).ToList();

FileNames.ForEach(x => Directory.Delete(x, true));
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to change the condition to this:

```
foreach(string r in dir.Where(x => x.Contains("AutomaticRecepes") == false && x.Contains("SpecialRecepes") == false))
{
    Directory.Delete(r, true);
}
```

`&&` is used to concat boolean expressions, but since `Where` returns an `IEnumerable`, it yields the error.

Comment: What exactly "didn't work". Please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

```
    dir.Where(x => !x.Contains("AutomaticRecepes") && !x.Contains("AutomaticRecepes"))
.ToList().ForEach(x=> Directory.Delete(x, true));
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var toExclude = new []{"AutomaticRecepes", "SpecialRecepes"};
var dir = Directory.GetDirectories(getDir()).Where(x => !toExclude.Any(y => x.Contains(y)));

foreach(string r in dir)
{
    Directory.Delete(r, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create a new instance of [`DirectoryInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) so you can check for the name of the folder. If you use [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) in the entire path of the folder and your folder's parent name has name of the excluded folder, your code won't work (for examplea directory named "to-delete" inside a folder "SpecialRecepes" won't be deleted).

```
var dirs = new DirectoryInfo(getDir()).EnumerateDirectories(getDir())
    .Where(x => x.Name != "AutomaticRecepes" && x.Name != "SpecialRecepes");

foreach (var dir in dirs)
{
    dir.Delete(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of the statement makes it hard to read and seems to confuse you. I would suggest making it more readable by breaking it up into multiple separate statements like this.

```
string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(getDir());

foreach (string dir in dirs) 
{
   if (!dir.Contains("AutomaticRecepes") &&
       !dir.Contains("SpecialRecepes")) 
   {
      Directory.Delete(dir, true);
   }
}
```

Like a wise man once said: "200 lines of obvious code beats 10 lines of 'clever' code" :)